# WP Revolution Slider - display problems

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, revolution-slider

I'm having trouble getting Revolution Slider (version 5.2.5.3) to work properly on my website and I'm looking for some help.

For reference the test page I'm using can be located here: http://www.capidale.co.uk/home-2

The problem I'm having is the background images on each slide are "zoomed" in. All images are 960x350 and I've set the grid settings also for 960x350. However, inspecting the code, the background images appear to being assigned values of 1653x549.

I've racked my brain but I just can't get it to work. I've tried using the images as "layers" and setting the background to transparent. But then I can't get the images to display at all.

Appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i have looked at the code and it says the natural values for the [image: Inspect Element]

Best best is to resize the images so they are 960x350 this should fix the issue if the image is zoomed still on the styling of the image set max-width:960; and max-height:350;

to save you the trouble use this image and replace the existing img, if it works then this is due to the natural sizes of the image

[image]

:D